# How to write junit test for a class that has member variables that are topComponents?

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

```
public class Something {

private static Something something = new  Something();

public static Something get(){
    return something;
}

private EventQueueWindow eventQueue;

private Something(){
    TopComponent tc = WindowManager.getDefault().findTopComponent("EventQueueWindow");
    eventQueue = (EventQueueWindow) tc;
}

EventQueue getQueue(){
    return eventQueue;
}

}//end class Something
```

Now I want to write a JUnit test which requires the ability to access eventQueue.

```
public void testgetQueue() {
    Something something = Something.get();
    assertEquals("Failed to return EventQueueWindow",something.getQueue().getClass(), EventQueueWindow.class);
}
```

I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I run the test because `eventQueue` has a `null` value despite it being assigned a value in class `Something's` constructor. I've read around that this may have something to do with components being handle in a different thread or not being initialized before the test is run. But I'm pretty new to java and unit testing and don't know how to solve this problem. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem is that you have global state. Global state is generally poor programming, including with tests.

Testing for particular implementation class, probably isn't a very good test.

I suggest removing your global state and dependency upon the global state that you are lumbered with from your libraries, then test that.

Comment: I realize the test is sort of stupid. I made the test up just so I could illustrate the problem. Which is basically that when I try to access a TopComponent in a JUnit test I always get a null back.

Comment: With regards to the `null`, presumably you have some cyclic static initialisation going on. Such problems would be much clearer without global state. A `Thread.dump` within the `Something` and `EventQueueWindow` constructors would probably illustrate the problem.

Comment: The application and code runs without error. If I simply run the application in debug mode and set break points at topComponent initialization points in Somethings's constructor they are not null. The issue is not with the code or program structure which I have greatly simplified for this post. The issue is with JUnit and how to write tests that involve TopComponents. 

 All the junit test that I have written have worked fine except for any involving TopComponents and accessing them. Something.getQueue().doWhatever() is what I want to be able to do but can't.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your suggestions and if that's the case I'm sorry.

Comment: @user2561417 So are you saying the behaviour is different when run as part of an application and when that application is a JUnit runner? In that case, is it something to do with the thread you are running on. Assuming AWT, then that's all thread-hostile. Simplest fix would be to shove everything within an `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait` (usually a bad call - the GUI will lock up/deadlock during the test). That could be moved out into code generating the tests. As I say, you really want to isolate yourself from globals, including that in the badly designed libraries.

Comment: Well unfortunately the design of this application is not up to me so I can't really change it. I'm a new addition and have been charged with writing unit test.

EventQueue is an instance of custom class called EventQueueWindow. So will I need to write an invokeAndWait method for the EventQueueWindow class or do I just say 

`@Test
 public voide testAddEvent(){

 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait( ~~JUnit test code which is dependent on being able to reference EventQueue)

}//end test`

Comment: As far as I know the application we are working on is not multithreaded.

Comment: @user2561417 There isn't really such a thing in Java. You'll probably have one the windowing system is running on, and one JUnit is running your tests on. (If there weren't globals then the multithreading would be more explicit.)

Comment: So to be clear the java.awt.EventQueue and the eventQueue I'm trying to access aren't the same thing. Just a sad coincidence that they are similarly named. So I'm not sure if that's going to change your answer or not. In my application eventQueue is a TopComponent that has been cast as a custom class called EventQueueWindow.

Comment: @user2561417 I don't know what `TopComponent` is. My guess is that you are using a library which does its own thing with threads, and that causes the problem together with globals.

Comment: "org.openide.windows.TopComponent is a JComponent subclass which knows how to work with the NetBeans window system. If you want to add components to the main window, typically you will subclass TopComponent, using it the same way you would a JPanel. TopComponents are part of the Windows API. "
Sounds like they are a netbeans specific thing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is going on is that the class is designed to exist inside a large context. `WindowManager` gives the class access to that context but the context does not exist in the unit test therefore the manager returns null.

One solution is to have two overloads of the constructor with one taking the `WindowManger` as an argument. Then in the test pass a mocked `WindowManager` to this constructor.

Mocking example via [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/):

```
 WindowManager man = Mockito.mock(WindowManager.class);
 EventQueueWindow window = Mockito.mock(EventQueueWindow.class);
 Mockito.when(man.findTopComponent("EventQueueWindow")).thenReturn(window);
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with mocking but this sounds like it could be the problem.